# Can I serve a static page while my Azure Cloud Services role restarts?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a single-instance nodejs web app hosted on Azure Cloud Services. I'm having a problem with it right now that sometimes causes node to crash and the role to restart. While I'm trying to hunt down this problem, is it possible to configure the cloud service to serve a static page when the role is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only a single instance of your web role, there's really not much you can do when your app is down (or rebooting), regarding redirection to a static web page. This *could* be done at the dns level, and you could take advantage of something like Traffic Manager to redirect requests somewhere else (perhaps to a single-page website somewhere, such as Azure Websites). There's really no "right" answer as to where you'd redirect, or how you'd do it, but aside from having multiple role instances running, there's really no way to have a static landing-page area for your requests.